# how to reduce number of requests to server in extjs

Tags: charts, extjs4.2

I am currently working on Charts in ExtJS, it is taking much time to display the graphs in browser.
Because the number of requests sending to server are more only for graphs.
How to reduce these no.of requests and improve the performance of my graph in EXTJS.

Can you help me regarding this ?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Ext Direct](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/extdirect) for its method batching support?

The idea is that you should receive data in a few large requests, rather than many smaller ones.  Each browser has a maximum number of outgoing requests (I think 6 is the default now), so if you are making more requests than this, then they will queue client side.

Comment: No..I am not aware of Ext Direct .Is there any way to reduce the number of Extjs library files,because there are more files in library due to this its taking much time i think

Comment: You can use a JS compiler to bundle everything together into a single minified file.  For example, Google's closure compiler.